# "add rest api client" I can't add my rest api

Tags: rest, azure, visual-studio-2017

In vs2017, I have created an Asp.Net web application by choosing "Web Api" and check "MVC" and "Web Api".

I added an "Ado.net Entity Data Model", chose "Ef Designer from Database" and added my table.

I built the project, right click controllers --> add controller "Web api 2 Controller with actions, using Entity Framework" with model class: Contact

Then I added swagger.

Published it to Azure & tested it through Swagger. Everything works well.

When I create a client application, add a rest api client and click "Select Azure Asset", only a few apps are shown and my azure app is not showing.

What does an app need to be shown in this selection box?

Answer (score 2):

> only a few apps are shown and my azure app is not showing.

Only Azure API App will be shown in the Azure Asset Window. When you create the Azure Web App from Visual Studio, you need to choose API App as the app type.

[image]

If you have already created the app on Azure, you need to set the API definition location from Azure portal. After that, you will see the API app in Azure Asset Window.

[image]

Comment: Any update? If your issue is solved, please mark my reply as answer. A thread which has been marked as answer will be searched easily. It will help others who encounter similar issues.